# Formula of permutation with similar objects

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to prove formally the formula for a permutation of $m$ elements of a set $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ so that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}_n$, $x_i$ is repeated $m_i$ times:

$$\text{PR}_{m;m_1,\ldots,m_n}=\dfrac{m!}{m_1!\cdots m_n!}.$$

In class, we see the following proof but I need to justify something I clear afterwards:

Let consider the following set:

$$\widetilde{X}=\left\{x_{i_j}\mid i \in \mathbb{N}_n, j = j(i) \in \mathbb{N}_{n_i} \right\}.$$

Let $\Phi:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be defined like $\Phi(x_{i_j})=x_i$.

If $A:=\text{P}\left(\widetilde{X}\right)$ denotes the set of permutations of $\widetilde{X}$ and $B:=\text{PR}_{m;m_1,\ldots,m_n}(X)$ the set of permutations of $m$ elements of a set $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ so that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}_n$, $x_i$ is repeated $m_i$ times, we can construct a map $\Psi:A\rightarrow B$ as follows:

$$\Psi(u_1,\ldots,u_m)=(\Phi(u_1),\ldots,\Phi(u_m)).$$

**We claim that $\left|\Psi^{-1}(\{v\})\right|=m_1!\cdots m_n!$** for all $v\in B$.

Despite the fact that $\Psi$ is not injective, it's surjective. Then:

$$A=\bigcup_{v\in B}{\Psi^{-1}(\{v\})}.$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{array}{l}
    m!=\left|A\right|=\left|\bigcup_{v\in B}{\Psi^{-1}(\{v\})}\right|=\sum_{v\in B}\left|\Psi^{-1}(\{v\})\right|=\\
    \\
    \sum_{v\in B}{(m_1!\cdots m_n!)} = \text{PR}_{m;m_1,\ldots,m_n} \cdot (m_1!\cdots m_n!). 
\end{array}$$

How can you prove formally (using bijections between finite sets) that $\left|\Psi^{-1}(\{v\})\right|=m_1!\cdots m_n!$ for all $v\in B$?

Comment: See Proposition 2.12.7 in [my *Enumerative Combinatorics*](https://darijgrinberg.gitlab.io/t/19fco/n/n.pdf) (I use the numbers $i$ instead of the $x_i$, but this is equivalent by an obvious bijection). The proof defers mostly to Proposition 2.12.5, whose rigorous proof is given in §7.56 ("Solution to Exercise 2.12.1"). Note that this proof has a huge "de Bruijn factor"; several pages consist of straightforward reasoning to justify  intuitively obvious claims.

Comment: Note that I do not answer your question at the end of your post; I prove the formula $\text{PR}_{m;m_1,\ldots,m_n}=\dfrac{m!}{m_1!\cdots m_n!}$ differently.

Comment: Your question seems to be answered in Chapter III, §5, Section 8 (specifically, in the proof of Proposition 11, on page 180) of [Bourbaki's *Theory of Sets*](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=914D557DA824CEC5B108F667CB118E0A). I'm saying "seems" because the argument seems to be spread across the book, but I'm hoping Bourbaki is rigorous enough.

Comment: In Bourbaki's book, I went to page 180 and in order to prove what I said, it says that I must go to chapter II, section 4, subsection number 7 and proposition 8, but I don't see the relationship between my question and the result shown on that page.